# Beginner making a Console app survival game, unsure on how to generate room positions on a square grid

Tags: c#, console-application, adventure

I'll go over what I have so far and then explain the problem.

I have a class called Room, and each room has an XPos and a YPos, as well as multiple other parameters that aren't relevant. Up until now, I have been assigning these values in the main method, manually making a new Room with specified values. This has gotten impractical and boring, so I decided to try randomly generating the rooms.

I started off by making a method called GenerateRooms, with a return type of List. This is assigned to the rooms list which is communicated with at runtime.
GenerateRooms:

```
private static List<Room> GenerateRooms(int gridSize)
    {
        RandomRoomGenerator randomRoomGenerator = new RandomRoomGenerator();
        int numRooms = gridSize * gridSize;
        List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numRooms; i++)
        {
            rooms.Add(randomRoomGenerator.GenerateRoom(gridSize, rooms));
        }

        return rooms;
    }
```

As you can see, it also takes in a parameter called gridSize. This is the length/width of the world. It is used later in my attempts to generate room positions.
Inside GenerateRoom, I assign values to a room constructor. For things like the room's description or items, I haven't had too many problems randomizing, but the position has given me a lot of trouble.

GenerateRoom:

```
public class RandomRoomGenerator
{
    public Room GenerateRoom(int gridSize, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        RandomRoomDescriptions randomRoomDescriptions = new RandomRoomDescriptions();
        RandomItemGenerator randomItemGenerator = new RandomItemGenerator();
        ItemDB itemDb = new ItemDB();

        string description = randomRoomDescriptions.roomDescriptions[new Random().Next(0, randomRoomDescriptions.roomDescriptions.Count)];

        Room room = new Room(description, GenerateXPos(rooms, gridSize), GenerateYPos(rooms, gridSize), new Random().Next(1, 7), new Random().Next(1, 7), new Random().Next(1, 7), randomItemGenerator.GenerateRandomItems(itemDb));
        return room;
    }

    private int GenerateXPos(List<Room> rooms, int gridSize)
    {
        int xPos = 0;

        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (room.XPos == xPos)
            {
                xPos++;
                if (xPos == gridSize)
                {
                    return xPos;
                }
            } 
        }


        return xPos;

    }

    private int GenerateYPos(List<Room> rooms, int gridSize)
    {
        int yPos = 0;

        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (room.XPos == gridSize && room.YPos == yPos)
            {
                yPos++; 
                return yPos;
            }
        }

        return yPos;

    }
```

With the code you can see here, I am able to create a horizontal line of rooms three rooms long, as well as six stacked rooms at (3, 1).

The problem: I need to make it so that GenerateXPos only iterates through rooms on the current row. I have tried making a variable called YPos in the GenerateRoom class and incrementing it whenever XPos reaches GridSize, but that didn't work.

What I think another solution could be would be removing the need for an X and Y pos in the Room constructor alltogether, and assign the positions in the main method. But that's kinda the last resort. I want to grow my experience and de-mystify coding so I can learn better. If I didn't give enough info, let me know. Here's some relevant classes just in case:
Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the wasteland.");
        List<Room> rooms = GenerateRooms(3);
        var currentRoom = rooms[0];



        Player player = new Player(100, 10, 10, 10, 0,0);
        player.Inventory.Add(player.CurrentWeapon = new Weapon("Fists", "Regular fists.", 1));

        GameState.GameStates currentGameState = GameState.GameStates.Exploring;


        while (player.Health > 0 && player.Hunger < 50 && player.Thirst < 50 && player.Radiation < 50)
        {
            while (currentGameState == GameState.GameStates.Exploring)
            {
                Input.HandleExplorationInput(player, ref currentRoom, rooms, ref currentGameState);

            }

            while (currentGameState == GameState.GameStates.Fighting)
            {
                Input.HandleEncounterInput(player, currentRoom.Enemy, player.CurrentWeapon, ref currentGameState, currentRoom);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You died!");

    }
```

Room:

```
public class Room
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int XPos { get; set; }
    public int YPos { get; set; }
    public int HungerToAdd { get; set; }
    public int ThirstToAdd { get; set; }
    public int RadiationToAdd { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public Enemy Enemy { get; set; }


    //Description, coord, and stats.
    public Room(string description, int xPos, int yPos, int hungerToAdd, int thirstToAdd, int radiationToAdd)
    {
        this.Description = description;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;
        this.HungerToAdd = hungerToAdd;
        this.ThirstToAdd = thirstToAdd;
        this.RadiationToAdd = radiationToAdd;
    }

    //Description, coord, stats, and items.
    public Room(string description, int xPos, int yPos, int hungerToAdd, int thirstToAdd, int radiationToAdd, List<Item> items)
    {
        this.Description = description;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;
        this.Items = items;
        this.HungerToAdd = hungerToAdd;
        this.ThirstToAdd = thirstToAdd;
        this.RadiationToAdd = radiationToAdd;
    }

    //Description, coord, stats, items, and enemy.
    public Room(string description, int xPos, int yPos, int hungerToAdd, int thirstToAdd, int radiationToAdd, List<Item> items, Enemy enemy)
    {
        this.Description = description;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;
        this.Items = items;
        this.Enemy = enemy;
        this.HungerToAdd = hungerToAdd;
        this.ThirstToAdd = thirstToAdd;
        this.RadiationToAdd = radiationToAdd;

    }

    //Description, coord, stats, and enemy.
    public Room(string description, int xPos, int yPos, int hungerToAdd, int thirstToAdd, int radiationToAdd, Enemy enemy)
    {
        this.Description = description;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;
        this.Enemy = enemy;
        this.HungerToAdd = hungerToAdd;
        this.ThirstToAdd = thirstToAdd;
        this.RadiationToAdd = radiationToAdd;

    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of extraneous code; can you reduce your question to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't see the difference between this and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980644/)

Comment: @DourHighArch because I tried to make my question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem what you what is a way to create a grid of rooms (cells that have a width and height = gridSize) in which you have several properties. One of which is a room description. This room description should be randomly selected from a list you have (somewhere). For that all you really need to do is create a list (`HashSet` in this case--see why below) of random integers, whereby the maximum value in the `HashSet` should be at most the maximum number of elements in your "randomRoomDescriptions" List (or Array?).

Therefore, your code can be greatly simplified.

The `Room` class could look like:

```
public class Room
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int XPos { get; set; }
    public int YPos { get; set; }
    public int HungerToAdd { get; set; }
    public int ThirstToAdd { get; set; }
    public int RadiationToAdd { get; set; }
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }
    public string Enemy { get; set; }

    //Description, coord, and stats.
    public Room(string description, int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        CreateDescriptionList();
        Random rand = new Random();

        this.Description = description;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;
        this.HungerToAdd = rand.Next(1, 7);
        this.ThirstToAdd = rand.Next(1, 7);
        this.RadiationToAdd = rand.Next(1, 7);
        //this.Items = do something here!
        //this.Enemy = "Fred"; //Do something here, too!
    }
}
```

Now simply populate the `Room` List "rooms":

```
        var maxGrid = 3;
        var rooms = CreateRandomRooms(maxGrid);
```

using the following methods:

```
    private List<Room> CreateRandomRooms(int grid)
    {
        RandomRoomDescriptions randomRoomDescriptions = new RandomRoomDescriptions();
        var listRooms = new List<Room>();
        var rand = GetRandomRoomIndicies(grid, Room.maxDecriptionEntries);

        int index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < grid; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < grid; y++)
            {
                var i = rand.ElementAt(index);
                var descr = randomRoomDescriptions.roomDescriptions[i];
                var room = new Room(descr, x, y);
                listRooms.Add(room);
                index++;
            }
        }

        return listRooms;
    }



    private HashSet<int> GetRandomRoomIndicies(int grid, int maxRand)
    {
        int minRand = 0;
        int maxCount = grid * grid;
        var rand = new Random();

        var randHashset = new HashSet<int>();

        while (randHashset.Count < maxCount)
        {
            randHashset.Add(rand.Next(minRand, maxRand));
        }

        return randHashset;
    }
```

The key to this is basically the method "GetRandomRoomIndicies". It creates a `HashSet` of random integer values (max value = max number of Descriptions in description List). This `HashSet` will be used to get a random description from your list and use it to describe the `Room`. While creating the `Room` a random number generator is used to populate things like "Hunger", "Thirst" and "Radiation". You will need to do something about "Items" and "Enemy".

The nice thing about the `HashSet` is it will only allow unique values to be added. So you just keep "Adding" until the collection has reached the size you want.